# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, customization, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to write a fetch xml to retrieve BusinessUnitID and Equipment ID from Facility/Equipment Entity, i have written this fetch xml in c# code, but it throws a null reference exception/System.NullReferenceException in the line (BOLD'ed line)
I don't any have null values in the facility/equipment entity.
Here is my code:

```
  private static OrganizationService _orgService;
  string fetchBU = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
    <entity name='equipment'>
        <attribute name='name' />
        <attribute name='equipmentid' />
        <order attribute='name' descending='false' />
      <filter type='and'>
         <condition attribute='businessunitid' operator='eq-businessid' />
      </filter>
    </entity>
   </fetch>";

EntityCollection ec = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchBU));
if (ec.Entities.Count > 0)
{
   Guid BusinessUnitId = (Guid)ec[0].Attributes["businessunitid"];
}
```

[image]

Can someone please suggest me on this ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `businessunitid` also inside the attributes, not only in the condition:

```
string fetchBU = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
    <entity name='equipment'>
        <attribute name='name' />
        <attribute name='equipmentid' />
        <attribute name='businessunitid' />
        <order attribute='name' descending='false' />
      <filter type='and'>
         <condition attribute='businessunitid' operator='eq-businessid' />
      </filter>
    </entity>
   </fetch>";
```

Comment: Hi guido  First of all thanks for answering the query. I am still getting the same error. Please have a look at image added above.

Comment: then _orgService is not initialized with your connection details

Comment: Thanks! there was a problem with connection.